# get count of next sibling until in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a web page where I have to show/hide li based on next li count.

In my scenario I have to show/hide li with class '**alpha-bg**' based on next visible li's (having class '**myContacts_**') count, if count>0 then show else hide. The count of next li(sibling) is until another li having class '**alpha-bg**'. TIA.

```
<ul id="contact-screen">
      <li class="alpha-bg">Favorite</li>
      <li class="myContacts_" style="display: none;">Henry</li>
      <li class="alpha-bg">J</li>
      <li class="myContacts_" style="display: none;">John</li>
      <li class="myContacts_">Jordon</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.alpha-bg').each(function(index){
    var length = 0;  // set length to 0 foreach .alpha-bg
    $(this).nextUntil('.alpha-bg').each(function(){
        // loop trough all siblings until next .alpha-bg
        // if the sibling has display none we're not interested
        // so we skip that one
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
           return;
        }
        ++length;  // if sibling is not display: none; add it to length
    });

    if(length == 0) {  // if length of siblings is not bigger 0 hide .alpha-bg
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="contact-screen">
  <li class="alpha-bg">Favorite</li>
  <li class="myContacts_" style="display: none;">Henry</li>
  <li class="alpha-bg">J</li>
  <li class="myContacts_" style="display: none;">John</li>
  <li class="myContacts_">Jordon</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: thanks @caramba but the output should be  .J    .Jordon  not .Favorite .Jordon

Comment: @sunny701 sorry, fixed it. Is it now working for you?